# Correct usage of the idiom "We will cross that bridge when we come to it"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

For the idiom "We will cross that bridge when we come to it", shouldn't it be "We will cross that bridge when we **will** come to it"? If not, please help me understand how the latter is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: 'I will visit the Eiffel Tower when I am in Paris' vs 'I will visit the Eiffel Tower when I will be in Paris'.  The second will is redundant because the two events are linked.

Comment: My favorite version of the expression is "We'll fall off that bridge when we come to it."

Comment: Consider inverting it: “When we come to the bridge, we will cross it.”  It should be clearer that “will come” is not appropriate.

Comment: The group of people of which I am a member expects to traverse that arch at the time that it is is approached.

Comment: @Robusto - I prefer *we'll burn that bridge when we come to it*.

Comment: We'll burn this bridge once we cross it.

Answer (score 1):

In "We will cross that bridge when we come to it", "come" is the simple present tense used to indicate the present in the future.

It is very common:

"I **am** in Paris tomorrow - I'll speak to you then"

"John **leaves** in an hour, don't let him forget his coat."

In "when we come to it", when = at the time that, i.e. the present tense is used to create the present at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom in the title of the question is correct.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [**cross that bridge when one comes to it**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20that%20bridge%20when%20one%20comes%20to%20it):

> : to not worry about a possible problem until it actually happens
> // I don't know how we'll pay the bills if you quit your job, but *we'll cross that bridge when we come to it*.

---

Consider the following variations with only *when* or *will*:

> ✔ **When** we come to that at some point, we will cross it.
> ✔ We **will** come to that bridge at some point.

And also the following variations with both words:

> ✔ We don't know **when** we **will** come to that bridge.
> ✔ **When** we **will** come to that bridge is unknown.

However:

> ✘ **When** we **will** come to that bridge at some point, we will cross it.

It's this particular combination of *when* and *will* that is unnatural.

---

It seems that using *when* with *will* only forms an acceptable sentence if it's then followed by just a verbal phrase or just a verb and an adjective.

But using the combination in a dependent clause that introduces an independent clause is not idiomatic. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly why this would be, and I can't put the reason behind it into an actual rule.

However, I do know which version of the sentence is idiomatic and which isn't:

> ✔ We **will** cross that bridge when we come to it.
> ✘ We **will** cross that bridge when we **will** come to it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that usually, the word "will" isn't used after "if", "when", or similar words.

Examples:

*Incorrect:* When the sun will rise, I will get out of bed.
*Correct:* When the sun rises, I will get out of bed.

*Incorrect:* If you will see David tomorrow, say hello to him for me.
*Correct:* If you see David tomorrow, say hello to him for me.

*Incorrect:* After we will eat dinner, we will have dessert.
*Correct:* After we eat dinner, we will have dessert.

*Incorrect*: If Sarah will cross the finish line first, she will win the race.
*Correct:* If Sarah crosses the finish line first, she will win the race.

*Incorrect:* We will cross that bridge when we will come to it.
*Correct:* We will cross that bridge when we come to it.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-present-simple-to-talk-about-the-future-i-work-tomorrow)'s grammar section

> The present simple is used to refer to events in the future which are certain because they are facts, or because there is a clear or fixed schedule or timetable

with examples like

1. I work tomorrow
2. What time does their flight to Seoul leave?

The second example can be changed to "When does the flight to Seoul leave?" without a change in meaning. You can imagine the answer being something like "When the airplane is ready", not "When the airplane will be ready".

"When the time comes" is a similar usage of the present simple to refer to something in the future.